# Loading data from generator using tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, generator

I want to load data for my metric learning model, and the data generating function is the `get_data()`  function

```
def get_data():
    def my_generator():
        for i in range(10):
            anchor = list(np.expand_dims(cv2.imread('img1'), axis=0))
            positive = list(np.expand_dims(cv2.imread('img2'), axis=0)
            true = 0
            a = (true, anchor, positive)
            yield a

    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        my_generator,
        output_types=(tf.int64, tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor),
        output_shapes=(1, (1, 256, 256, 3), (1, 256, 256, 3))
    )

dataset = get_data()
```

when I run this code, I get the following error. I've tried to pass some other arguments to `output_types`, tf.float64 for example, but it doesn't work either. I think I do something wrong with the shapes, but I can't figure what.

> TypeError: Cannot convert value <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'> to a TensorFlow DType.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

As I thought, the problem was in shapes, this worked for me

```
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        my_generator,
        output_types=(tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64),
        output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape(None), tf.TensorShape((1, 256, 256, 3)), 
            tf.TensorShape((1, 256, 256, 3))))
```